# How to save each output by iteration of a loop in separate csv files

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file in which i calculate a startdate and enddate, these dates change by iteration each time between a range of dates. the code works fine but i don't know how to save each output seperately in csv files.

My current code saves the first output of the loop only and save it in different csv files.

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta,date
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
import glob
import pandas as pd



for firstdate in pd.date_range('2022-01-01', '2025-12-31', freq='MS'):
startdate = firstdate.date()
enddate = (startdate + MonthEnd(1)).date()
df['slicing_startdate'] = np.where(((df.contractstartdate.dt.date.isnull()) | 
 (df.contractstartdate.dt.date < startdate)), startdate, df.contractstartdate.dt.date)
df['slicing_enddate'] = np.where(((df.effectiveenddate.dt.date.isnull()) | (enddate < 
df.effectiveenddate.dt.date)), enddate, df.effectiveenddate.dt.date)

folder_path= r".../FileName.csv"
months = ['M1','M2','M3','M4','M5','M6','M7','M8','M9','M10','M11','M12','M13','M14','M15','M16','M17','M18','M19','M20','M21','M22','M23','M24','M25','M26','M27','M28','M29','M30','M31','M32','M33','M34','M35','M36']
    for month in months:
    p = Path(folder_path).parent.joinpath(f"BD_{month}.csv")
    if not p.is_file():
        df.to_csv(p,index=False)
    else:
        print('file exists')
```

So in each csv file under the name of BD_M1, BD_M2, ....etc i have the same slicingstardate = 01/01/2022 and slicingenddate = 31/01/2022. while the desired output is for each csv file i have the corresponding dates.

thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the second for loop and use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead, this way you link each `data_range` iteration to an increasing counter (`month`) in the same loop.

```py
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta,date
...

...

folder_path= r"../FileName.csv"

for month, firstdate in enumerate(pd.date_range('2022-01-01', '2025-12-31', freq='MS'), 1):
    startdate = firstdate.date()
    enddate = (startdate + MonthEnd(1)).date()
    df['slicing_startdate'] = np.where(((df.contractstartdate.dt.date.isnull()) | 
    (df.contractstartdate.dt.date < startdate)), startdate, df.contractstartdate.dt.date)
    df['slicing_enddate'] = np.where(((df.effectiveenddate.dt.date.isnull()) | (enddate < 
    df.effectiveenddate.dt.date)), enddate, df.effectiveenddate.dt.date)

    p = Path(folder_path).parent.joinpath(f"BD_M{month}.csv")
    if not p.is_file():
        df.to_csv(p,index=False)
    else:
        print('file exists')
```